# Computational complexity of unknown probability

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Assume that there is a job and many workers are available.
The following code may be a bad optimization idea. 
But it is just for analyzing the complexity.

```
A is a set of N worker
while (A is not empty)
{
  B=empty set
  foreach a1 in A
  {
    foreach a2 in A
    { 
       b= merge(a1, a2)
       if (b works better than a1 **and** b works better than a2) 
          add b to B
    }
  }
  A=B
}
```

The problem is that the probability of "b works better than a1 and a2" is unknown.
So, how to estimate the time complexity of the above code ?

Comment: what is `merge()`, what is `B` ?

Comment: Looks like constant-time operations. So it won't matter.

Comment: @Nico Schertler. Thanks for pointing out the problem. I corrected the code, A is updated inside the while loop.
merge() means a1 and a2 are combined to be a group of workers. That is, 'A' initially contains group of single workers. Then, 'A' gradually contains bigger groups. 
Assume that the complexity is counted as the number of 'if' statement.

Comment: I don't think the question contains enough information as-is. For example, in this pseudo-code, A changes inside the outer foreach. What does that mean? Secondly, it looks like `B` only ever increases in size, so `A` can never be empty (unless `B` starts empty and nothing is ever added to `B`) -- which means the code never terminates.

Comment: @PaulHankin When the "if" is not hold for any pair of a1 and a2, B is empty.  A changes inside the while, not the outer foreach. I put a bracket to make it clearer. You are correct that B is initialized empty inside the while. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't think the question contains enough information to answer. `works better than`, and `merge(a1, a2)` are not described at all. For example, if workers are positive integers, and `merge(a1, a2) = a1+a2` and `works better` means "is larger than", then the code never terminates. Other definitions will produce different results.

Comment: @PaulHankin We don't need to care about how 'work better' is measured. We also don't need to care what 'merge' technically does. The technical detail is varied for different problems. Imagine as an example that combining two persons a1 and a2 for doing one job is better than either a1 and a2 independently does or not.

Comment: @YumiF yes, the technical detail may vary for different problems, but the overall complexity of the code depends on those variations. I've shown above, for example, one variation where the code never terminates. So without some constraints on the definitions, it's impossible to answer the question.

Comment: @PaulHankin, So, please consider that it is designed for the problems on that it will stop. For example, merge' is union. In that case, the worst complexity is 2^N when all if is true. But in average, if we don't know the probability of the if statement, how to calculate? That is the main point of the question.

Answer (score -1):

For the two inner loops, the complexity is independent of probability of *"b works better than a1 and a2"*.
However, the code seems a bit broken as I don't find there is an exit to the *while* loop.
Not considering the *while* loop, the time complexity will be

> O(a1*a2) = O(N^2).

Recurrence equation will be

> T(N) = T(N-1) + C